# R connect to Thomson Reuters Eikon

Tags: r, reuters, thomson-reuters-eikon

I search through the Web and did not find out a package connecting to `Thomson Reuters Eikon`.

It's a financial datasource, more or less similar to `Bloomberg`. Bloomberg is supported through `R` with this package:

http://findata.org/r-name-redacted/

Seems there is nothing for `Reuters`, but maybe I am completely wrong? Ideally I would like to connect to a `Reuters` terminal and scrap some information automatically from `R`.

Comment: Seems like you'll have to create your own wrappers of the C++ or java API

Comment: I fear so! Hum if it's Java, I can have a look maybe to Rjava, dunno if it helps ...just an idea coming ..

Comment: In my experience, `rJava` suffers from several issues (memory constraints, dependency on java version). You'd better use the C API and use the very good `Rcpp` package to wrap it.

Comment: If its just equity prices or FRED data, have you checked out `quantmod`? http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/ It can handle different sources which may be of help.

Comment: I have the same problem. I will probably start by using dde (you can use `Tcltk2`) and then explore their C++ interface via a wrapper with `Rcpp`

Comment: Hi, I am building a package that might be useful for you, it is a fast R DDE connection. It is already funcional. https://bitbucket.org/juancentro/rdde

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE in 2017:
Thomson Reuters released the Eikon API (now in Beta) with a Python package. Please note that you do need a desktop-license to access the API. The information/documentation can be found on the [Developer Portal](https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/eikon-apis/eikon-web-and-scripting-apis). 
You can find an unofficial R-package on Github: https://github.com/ahmedmohamedali/eikonapir

**Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Thomson Reuters

Comment: Thanks. This suggests to me that using the python API in R through 
 [reticulate|https://cran.r-project.org/package=reticulate]  could be a simple and effective approach.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a package that connects Eikon to R. It still in alpha stage, with only basic functionality, but I use it daily with no issues.
You can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/juancentro/reikon).
Please leave any feedback or issues directly on Bitbucket's issue tracker

Comment: I came up with your package but in my company they are curious about the "legality" of it because Eikon offers an api (for python) but it cost and they don't want to get in any problems.

Comment: Alejandro, there is no issue. I have shared my package with Reuters. However, keep in mind that this is an old package, no longer maintained. There are newer (and still free) options. Check the Eikon Developers Forum or the other answers